# Understanding というところで?

Tags: grammar

> それからは先輩と学園のことや創作論についての話をして過ごした。
>
> 既に時間もいい**というところで**、駅まで送っていくことに。

How should I understand the 〜というところで? Is it interchangeable with から in this context? Or the two are always interchangeable? Could you please illustrate how to use 〜というところで in an abstract sense?

Answer (score 2):

「というところ」can mean "it is the case that..." "the situation is.." and so forth. The で can be understood more abstractly here as "by way of" or "with." Literally I would read it as "With the situation being that...." I can see this being similar to から in this sense.

「というところだ」is also an N1 grammar structure. Aというところだ is an expression meaning “the stage/level/degree that one would call A” and is used to describe a speaker's feelings/opinion/estimate/guess about the current stage/situation. The speaker is not completely sure, but the degree/amount is about/approximately A. Often implies that the amount/degree/activity is “at best” (usually together with せいぜい) A - it is below A level and the speaker does not consider it to be a big/important thing. Often used with phrases expressing quantity (quantifiers).

I would roughly understand this as "Already it was about time, so we decided to etc."

Answer (score 1):

The というところで in question can be understood as *at the point where*, the *point* referring to a point in time. As such it can be replaced by とき rather than から.

As you may understand, the most straightforward というところ is *a place called* (e.g. ヨークというところで = *in a city called York*). This still can be understood as the same *at the point where*, but the point is in space.

---

Another related but different というところで is when the last で is a form of だ. It works as a blurring of the statement, meaning *It is something like that...*.

- なんとかうまくいったいうところです *It is like that I have got it done successfully* =*I have got it done successfully with some reservations*,

but it depends on what reservations there are. The speaker may have had a total success, but just wants to make it sound modest. Or there are certain things the speaker is not satisfied with.

Yet another case is that there is some omission after というところ. Consider e.g.,

- 今月は感染者数が少なかったが、正月で人の移動が増えるとどうかというところです。 *There were few infection cases this month, but **the issue is** what the number will be when more people go out around new year's holidays.*

The omission depends on the context, but usually *the issue is, I wonder, I'm not sure about* (というところ**が問題です/私は疑問です/私にははっきりわかりません**).